# Insert Timestamp on value change from other table

Tags: trigger, timestamp

I have an `EvidenceTimeStamp` table that is triggered with data when the case table has data inserted into it.

`EvidenceTimeStamp`:

- `CaseID`
- `EvidenceNum`
- `EvidenceType`
- `Evidence_Initiated_Timestamp`
- `Evidence_Returned_Timestamp`

I created a trigger to fill the first four columns of data whenever a new case is inserted in the case table and it creates a timestamp on `Evidence_Initiated_Timestamp` when this happens.

However, I need to create a closing timestamp when the process is complete. I wanted to do this by my Outbound Ship Table- everytime the Attribute (bit value) `Outbound_Item_Recevied` is changed from false to true (or 0 to 1) I want it to initate a timestamp on the `Evidence_Returned_Timestamp` column in my `EvidenceTimeStamp` table that matches the corresponding `CaseID` and `EvidenceNum`.

Note: the `EvidenceTimeStamp` table does not have a primary key or foreign key technically... the `CaseID` is primary key in the `Case` table and `EvidenceNum` is an attribute in the `Evidence` Table. This is a "trigger" table so it really doesn't have its own specific data, it's just filling data from other tables.

Any idea of how to do this?

Also, other quick question, how do I get bit values to show "True" or "False" instead of 1 or 0? Thank you!!

Comment: Does your `Outbound Ship` table has `CaseId` and `EvidenceNum` column?

Comment: Yes,..... It does. But "Ship ID" is primary key, but that won't be used. Just had to throw a PK in there to keep it unique. CaseID is FK in that table

Comment: Can't you have another trigger based on `CaseID` and `EvidenceNum`? If you add schema of all 3 tables might help folks answer your question.  On your 2nd question you have to use a case statement to see `True` and `False`.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to do that. I am very new with SQL

Comment: I suggest you post schema of all 3 tables with few rows of sample data.  Somebody will be able to answer your question if it is doable.

Comment: And, as always, it helps to make sure that you tag the question with your DBMS, "sql" simply refers to the SQL language in general. If you're using MS SQL Server, then add the "sql-server" tag, along with the tag for your version.

Answer (score 0):

Logically (based on the names of your tables), a particular item of evidence cannot be checked out to more than one person at once. We'll assume, then, that no more than one `EvidenceTimeStamp` table record for a given `CaseID` and `EvidenceNum` should have a NULL `Evidence_Returned_Timestamp`.

In that case, you'd need a trigger on your Outbound Ship Table with something like the following in it:

```
UPDATE ets
   SET ets.Evidence_Returned_Timestamp = GETDATE()
  FROM EvidenceTimeStamp ets
         INNER JOIN inserted I ON (    ets.CaseID = i.CaseID
                                   AND ets.EvidenceNum = i.EvidenceNum
                                  )
 WHERE i.Outbound_Item_Recevied = 1
   AND ets.Evidence_Returned_Timestamp IS NULL
;
```

(SQL Server syntax; modify as needed for other platforms)

This will work whether you're modifying/inserting one record or many in the Outbound Ship Table. *However*, this will update *all* rows for the given `CaseID` and `EvidenceNum` pair(s) that currently have NULL in `Evidence_Returned_Timestamp`, so if you *can* have more than one open row for a specific `CaseID` and `EvidenceNum`, you'll need some other way to find the right row(s) to update.

(To clarify: If you've got open entries for case 123, evidence numbers 2 and 7, and case 456, evidence numbers 3 and 7, and you updated an Outbound Ship item for case 123, evidence num 7, then the other three open entries are fine.  However, if you had *two* `EvidenceTimeStamp` rows with case 123, evidence number 7, then *both* of them would have their `Evidence_Returned_Timestamp` set.)

NOTE: Every table should have a column (or group of columns) that is guaranteed to uniquely identify every row in the table and it (or they) really should be the primary key. You may not want to set that up as a clustered index, but you enforce uniqueness by making that the primary key.